# Why does THotKey not have an Align property and how can I add it?

Tags: delphi, hotkeys, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10, I tried to use a `THotKey` control to enter hotkeys. Since I use the `Align` property a lot to create a neat UI, I wondered why `THotKey` does not have an `Align` property. Even `TRzHotKeyEdit`, `TJvHotKey`, and `TJvDotNetHotKey` do not have an `Align` property.

Is it possible to simulate a `THotkey.Align` property? Or is there another HotKey control with an `Align` property?

Comment: It is a TControl descendant, use a "protected hack" to access the property. This doesn't of course answer why the property is not published.

Comment: The answer is so simple that it hardly is worth an answer: "Because no one thought of publishing it."

Comment: I can simply use the `Align` property programmatically at run-time, for example: `HotKey1.Align := alBottom;`. But is there a "diabolic" trick to publish the `Align` property in the Object Inspector, so I can use it at design time - without having to write a new component descending from `THotkey`?

Comment: What would he the point of this, isn't this a non-visual control? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The [`THotKey`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.THotKey) control is a visual control indeed. It wraps the [`HOTKEY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/hot-key-controls) Win32 control. (Also, I know you know this, but of course you mean "non-visual component". A control is by definition visual.)

Comment: @user1580348 in a word, no. In order to appear in the OI at design-time, the property must be declared as `published` to generate RTTI, and the component must be put in a package that is installed into the IDE. Which in this case means deriving a new component if you want the design-time support. [File a report with Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com) if you want the property to be published natively in a future release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unit to use it as a new component derived from `THotKey`:

```
unit ExtHotKey;

// Published the Align property

interface

uses
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TExtHotKey = class(THotKey)
  published
    property Align;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  System.Classes.RegisterComponents('PAComponents', [TExtHotKey]);
end;

end.
```

Then insert it into a new or existing package and install the package.

After that, the `Align` property is available in the Object Inspector and it works perfectly:

[image]